# Regular expression for determining specific characteristics of a string (that is a poker hand)

Tags: php, regex

I have a string in the form of "AsKcQsJd" that represents 4 cards from a deck of playing cards. The uppercase value represnts the card value (in this case, Ace, King, Queen, and Jack) and the lowercase value represents the suit (in this case, spade, club, spade, diamond).

Say I have another value that tells me what suit I'm looking for. So in this case, I have:

`$hand = 'AsKcQsJd';
$suit = 's';`

How can I write a regular expression that checks if the hand has an Ace in it, followed by the suit, so in this case 'As' and also any other card that has the suit? Or in 'poker terms', I'm trying to determine if the hand has the 'ace high flush draw' for the suit defined as $suit.

To further explain, I need to check if any combination of the following two cards exist:

AsKs, AsQs, AsJs, AsTs,As9s,As8s,As7s,As6s,As5s,As4s,As3s,As2s

With the added complexity that these cards could occur anywhere in the hand. For example, the string could have As at the front and Ks at the end. That's why I think a regular expression is the best method for determining if the two coexist in the string.

Answer (score 3):

You might use two lookaheads, one for `As`, and one for `[^A]s`, like this:

```
(?=.*As)(?=.*[^A]s)
```

https://regex101.com/r/8hkWTv/1

```
$suit = 's';
$re = '/(?=.*A' . $suit . ')(?=.*[^A]' . $suit . ')/';
print($re); //    /(?=.*As)(?=.*[^A]s)/
print(preg_match($re, 'AsKcQsJd')); // 1
print(preg_match($re, 'AdKcQsJd')); // 0
print(preg_match($re, 'KsKcQsJd')); // 0
```

Comment: I wasn't thinking about efficiency, lookahead without consuming characters is just the first thing that popped into my head when I saw the problem. Your alternation looks to take fewer steps, though.

Comment: What did I do wrong in the PHP? The code runs fine and doesn't give any warnings that I see (though, of course, the results are all printed on one line at the moment) Though, I'm not experienced with PHP so I wouldn't be surprised at all if I made a silly mistake..?

Comment: `$suite` appears to be replacing both `.*As` and `A` in your regex, but only contains `s` (the suite).  I'm not exactly sure what `$re` should be but probably something where `$suite` only replaces the `s` in the regex?

Comment: Oops, you're right, thanks. I got the regex but didn't get the dynamic construction of the RE right

Comment: for what it's worth, I was very curious about the performance side of this and built a script to compare your regex and mine on a large array of different hands - both did very well but yours out performs mine by approx 1/100th of a second.  avg time was .15 seconds vs .16 seconds to check 1,000,000 hands

Comment: Ok, tried this again on php 5 and had a drastically different result - in this case the alternation regex is over 100% faster.  I'm a bit confused about this but suffice to say, it's probably micro-optimization at this level and there doesn't seem to be any overwhelming performance benefit on either side

Comment: @billynoah Performance of this regex can be improved by 1.) only triggering the lookahead at `^` start of the string 2.) don't use a second lookahead 3.) remove greed inside first lookahead: [`^(?=.*?As).*[^A]s`](https://regex101.com/r/8hkWTv/2)

Comment: there's something very strange happening when I run benchmarks on php5 vs php7+.  The suggestion you made is way faster on php5, but slightly slower on php7.  I'm assuming this has something to do with php7 caching results on duplicate hands - it's just me speculating and this is probably off topic now

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure regex is the best solution but if that's your cup of tea you can do it pretty easily with alternation like this:

```regex
As.*s|s.*As
```

Or better yet - to capture the actual cards giving you a match:

```regex
(As).*(.s)|(.s).*(As)
```

These basically say - the hand has a spade followed by an ace of spades OR has ace of spades followed by any other spade. https://regex101.com/r/pdwHPQ/1

That said, I'd probably consider building a simple class to parse the hand and give you more flexibility when it comes to answering questions about what cards are present.  Whether or not this is worth it really depends a lot on your app.  Here's an idea:

```
$hand = 'AsKh4c5c9h2s';
$cards = new Cards($hand);
$spades = $cards->getCardsBySuit('s');

if (in_array('As',array_keys($spades)) && count($spades) > 1) {
    // hand has ace high flush draw
    echo 'yep';
}

class Cards {

    private $cards = '';

    public function __construct($hand) {
        foreach (str_split($hand,2) as $card) {
            $this->cards[$card] = [
                'rank' => substr($card,0,1),
                'suit' => substr($card,1,1)
            ];
        }
    }

    public function getCardsBySuit($suit) {
        $response = [];
        foreach ($this->cards as $k => $card) {
            if ($card['suit'] == $suit) {
                $response[$k] = $card;
            }
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```